# Python - Read system information (CPU core usage and temperatures)

Tags: python-2.7, cpu, cpu-usage, temperature

I want to start work on a project but I need help monitoring the CPU core usage and temperatures with python.

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Using Python 2.7, Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

The `psutil` library will give you some system information (CPU / Memory usage) on a variety of platforms. `psutil is a module providing an interface for retrieving information on running processes and system utilization (CPU, memory) in a portable way by using Python, implementing many functionalities offered by tools like ps, top and Windows task manager`

It currently supports Linux, OS X, FreeBSD and Windows with Python versions from 2.4 to 3.1 by using a unique code base.

Comment: Sorry wont work. It is out of date and not compatible with the latest CPUs.